# How to remove leading whitespace in MVC EditorFor decimal values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have got a database in SQL linked to my Visual Studio project. One of the columns in the database is decimal(5,2) and I REALLY need it to display to one decimal place.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0: 0.0}")]
public decimal Points { get; set; }
```

The above works well for the Index view (which uses a DisplayFor), but in the Edit view, I'm using EditorFor (see below)

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Points, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

The decimal number will display in the Edit view to one decimal place, but the field has a leading whitespace that you have to manually remove before you can save changes- even if you do not want to edit that value.

I have been trying to work this out for hours and it's driving me crazy. I have changed the database to have the values as decimal(5,1), but this has caused too many complications and is not working.

Is there a solution which doesn't involve editing the database ?

Comment: Because you have a leading space in your format string! Change it to `DataFormatString = "{0:0.0}"`

Comment: Display format may format the value, but you should double that up with [RegularExpression] validation as well to enforce the single decimal point.  Especially if not using some JavaScript control to enforce the value.